# Can entities be suplied to the UI withoud duplication in the viewmodal?

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, mvvm

I am new to this and cannot seem to find/Google a concise answer.

I am making a WPF application and trying to follow the MVVM pattern. I am modeling a database with 100+ tables. The EntityFramework entities are auto-generated on my machine. I am using a WCF service to access the local modal (the database is on another machine). My ViewModal loads/saves the data by access to the WCF service, and the EntityFramework communicates with the database.

Following the MVVM pattern, my Views use the ViewModel as their data context.

In keeping with the MVVM pattern, do I have to copy the tables/entities from the Modal to the ViewModel in order to bind to the UI?  (This would be quite extensive with 100+ tables).

In particular, I would like to be able to edit one or more fields on multiple records of the same table before saving the entire table back to the database. I do not wish to create copies of the classes of each entity in the viewmodel.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here depends a bit on the perspective of individual people.  Many people (myself included) have no problem with allowing the ViewModel to expose Model data to the View directly, which means you could just bind directly to your entities in the View.  For this to work, the ViewModel can just have a property that directly contains the matching Model instances.

Comment: I'm a little confused...is the DataContext the Model or the ViewModel, and if its the ViewModel, what does the property look like in the ViewModel that would expose the entity in the Model for UI binding?

Comment: @AlanWayne It can be either - you can use a VM, and bind to "Model.Foo", or just use the Model directly.  If it's a collection, binding to "Models" from ItemsSource works well

Comment: Thanks. It seems that if I put my business logic in partial classes along side the auto-generated EntityFramework classes, I could just about bypass the ViewModel all together?? i.e., View-to-Model?

Comment: @AlanWayne You'll need something to "glue" things together, most likely - don't put things that are specific to that application in there - but general logic can be fine.